# Regex to match characters that must be escaped in a PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions), which shows what characters need to be escaped. However, I'm having a lot of trouble constructing a regex that will match any instance of one of those characters in a string.

For some background on the problem, I'm implementing a simple word-for-word (or term-for-term if you prefer) translation database where users enter language pairs, and can then trigger translations on blocks of text. The problem comes when users enter strings like "Yes/No". So, in PHP, I need to escape the string to be matched, and place it like this:

```
"/\b".$target."\b/"
```

So, what do I need to be looking at in terms of a preg_replace?

Comment: I believe you want `preg_quote()` or `\Q` ... `\E`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php). As the documentation clearly states:

> `preg_quote()` takes str and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.

Or `\Q` ... `\E`, ( What's between `\Q` and `\E` is treated as normal characters, not regular expression characters. )